# Web-scraping with beautifulsoup in different siblings

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've tried different ways to scrape `Answer1` and `Answer2` from a website through BeautifulSoup, urllib and Selenium, but without success. Here's the simplified version:

```
<div class="div1">
  <p class="p1"></p>
  <p class="p2">
    <span>Question1</span>
    <strong>Answer1</strong>
    <br>
    <span>Question2</span>
    <strong>Answer2</strong>
    <br>
```

In selenium, I try to find `Question1`, then go to its parent and scrape `Answer1`. Below is the code I use, although it's not correct.

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Question1')]/parent::p/following::strong")
```

I believe bs is more efficient than selenium in this case. How would you do this in bs? Thanks!

**Edit:** @Juan's solution is perfect for my example. However, I realized it's inapplicable to the website https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL . Can anyone shed some light on parsing `Consumer Goods` and `Electronic Equipment` from there? And would it be better to use urllib.requests instead? Thank you.

Comment: Seems your question is incorrect as you want to `try to find Question1, then go to its parent and scrape Answer1` but your code attempt you did the reverse `"//span[contains(text(), 'Question1')]/parent::p/following::strong"`

Comment: @DebanjanB My end goal is to scrape `Answer1` and `Answer2`, and I think the most reliable way to correctly scrape both of these is to refer to `Question1`. Therefore, I search `Question1`, then go back to its parent and find both Answers. My logic should be correct, but not sure about my code.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it. I modified your html closing the tags p and div:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
html = """
<div class="div1">
  <p class="p1"></p>
  <p class="p2">
    <span>Question1</span>
    <strong>Answer1</strong>
    <br>
    <span>Question2</span>
    <strong>Answer2</strong>
    <br>
    </p>
</div>
"""
soup = BS(html,'lxml')
QA = {x.text:y.text for x,y in zip(soup.select('span'),soup.select('strong'))}
print(QA)
```

Comment: Thanks Juan, but it returns `{}`. Any idea?

Comment: In my computer returns:

`{'Question1': 'Answer1', 'Question2': 'Answer2'}`

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I was just trying on the website and it returned nothing.

Comment: You need to pass the html of the website. I use requests to get it:
   
 `import requests`;

    `url = 'http://www.example.com'`;

    `html = requests.get(url).text`;

And then parse with BS.
If the page have other span or strong tags, then you have to delimit. In this case could be:
`QA = {x.text:y.text for x,y in zip(soup.select_one('div[class="div1"]').select('span'),soup.select_one('div[class="div1"]').select('strong'))}`

Comment: It returns `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'select'`, so it seems that there's no such Class in the website according to the other thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/python-attribute-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something/8949265#8949265

Comment: The page you want to scrape is a little bit more complex that a simple static html. You have to be very specific identifying where is located the information you need.

Answer (score -1):

> div class="div1">
>
> Question1 **Answer1** 
>   Question2 **Answer2**

You only have to import and do it that with requests and beautifulsoup

```
Import request
From bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Url ="google.com"
R = requests.get(url)
Soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "lxml")
 For link in links:
    Soup.find_all("span")
    Print(link.text())
For answers in answer:
    Soup.find_all("strong")
    Print(answes.text)
```

And that my friend doing a membership check and a tuple that how you can do it.

Comment: It didn't solve my problem in the "Edit" part, but I appreciate your help regardless.